# Saleforce If statement Error

Tags: formula-field

Not sure why I am getting the error for having "

```
IF( Payoff_Amount__c -  Funding_Amount__c  > 0, Payoff_Amount__c - Funding_Amount__c , "None")
```

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'IF()'. Expected Number, received Text

Comment: i think your formula field  Number data type but you returned `None`

Answer (score 5):

Your formula is returning mixed types. If `Payoff_Amount__c - Funding_Amount__c > 0`, you return a number, `Payoff_Amount__c - Funding_Amount__c`. But otherwise, you return a string value, `"None"`.

Formulas must return a consistent type. If you want to use the word "None", you'd need to change your formula to a Text type and convert the dollar value to text as well, using the `TEXT()` function.